# TypeError: $(...).show(...).delay(...).fadeout is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am little new to jquery and trying to build a basic website with very minimal functionalities. So when I am doing this I am getting this weird error as below

```
TypeError: $(...).show(...).delay(...).fadeout is not a function
```

This is getting thrown at js function as shown below

```
$("#element_id").show().delay(5000).fadeout('slow');
```

Can anyone please help in this issue?

Comment: Have you tried `fadeOut` instead of `fadeout`

Comment: Folks, it's a typo question, why is my typo close vote so lonely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [`fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut) (capital `O`), not `fadeout`. JavaScript is case-sensitive.